# Table view: "Hide Empty Column" checkbox doesn't seem to work

Tags: views, 8

I've created a view, formatted as a table.

I'm trying to hide empty columns – so, in the table settings, I've checked the "Hide Empty Column" checkbox for most of the table columns.

However, this doesn't seem to have any effect – these columns are still included in the rendered table, with empty <td>s.

I expect this checkbox to hide the column entirely when all data cells contain an empty value. Am I understanding this correctly?

This certainly seems to be how it worked in Drupal 7. (I'm converting an existing D7 site to D8 – and this is how the table columns were hidden on the D7 site.)

Is there anything I should check which might be preventing this from working as expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Someone elsewhere suggested that I disable Twig debugging. This fixed this issue. Weird.